# Is there a better way to write this?

Tags: files, directories

I'm walking a directory tree upwards from `default-directory` in a loop, so I need a way to say "take the last component off this path that ends in a slash and return a result that ends in a slash". The closest built-in thing I found is `(file-name-directory)` and it's not a great fit. I ended up writing this:

```
(defun pop-dir (dir)
  "Pops a trailing directory off DIR to return the remainder of the path."
  (concat "/"
          ;; there's probably some better way to do this but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
          (string-join (reverse (cdr (reverse (split-string dir "/" t)))) "/")
          "/"))
```

There *has* to be a better way; what is it?

Comment: I am I correct in understanding `pop-dir` should return the parent directory of its argument? If so, you can write `(file-name-directory (directory-file-name FILENAME))` for any given `FILENAME`, regardless of whether it names a file or directory.

Comment: Please provide a more informative title for your post.

Comment: A couple of input-output examples could also prove very helpful.

Comment: As a general rule, you should use the functions that Emacs provides for manipulating file and directory names, not general string-manipulation functions such as `concat`. String functions really know nothing about files, directories, or their names.

Comment: What both @Basil and Dan said is important. State what you expect to use as input and what you would like to have as output, and put your summary request in the question title. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You say, "*take the last component off [a] path that ends in a slash and return a result that ends in a slash*".

Is this what you're looking for?  This is from [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) (but it doesn't depend on anything from Dired+.)

```el
(defun diredp-parent-dir (file &optional relativep)
  "Return the parent directory of FILE, or nil if none.
Optional arg RELATIVEP non-nil means return a relative name, that is,
just the parent component."
  (let ((parent  (file-name-directory (directory-file-name (expand-file-name file))))
        relparent)
    (when relativep (setq relparent  (file-name-nondirectory (directory-file-name parent))))
    (and (not (equal parent file))  (or relparent  parent))))
```